# Youtube Live API get game information

Tags: java, youtube-livestreaming-api

I would like to integrate with the youtube livestream api.

I noticed that many live streams on youtube show the game the streamer is currently playing when their stream is open in the browser. however, when looking at the api documentation, it seems that this information is missing.

Looking at other similar apis from streaming companies such as the Twitch and Mixer, this data is retrievable. I was hoping that someone could point me in the direction of how i can find it when dealing with youtube, or how i can put in a request to get this information added as i feel it would make the api more complete.

Here is a code example that illustrates what i am trying to do:

```
// This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for read-only access to the
        // authenticated user's account, but not other types of account access.
        List<String> scopes = Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly");

        try {
            // Authorize the request.
            Credential credential = Auth.authorize(scopes, "listbroadcasts");

            // This object is used to make YouTube Data API requests.
            youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                    .setApplicationName("youtube-cmdline-listbroadcasts-sample").build();

            // Create a request to list broadcasts.
            YouTube.LiveBroadcasts.List liveBroadcastRequest =
                    youtube.liveBroadcasts().list("id,snippet");

            // Indicate that the API response should not filter broadcasts
            // based on their type or status.
            liveBroadcastRequest.setBroadcastType("all").setBroadcastStatus("all");

            // Execute the API request and return the list of broadcasts.
            LiveBroadcastListResponse returnedListResponse = liveBroadcastRequest.execute();
            List<LiveBroadcast> returnedList = returnedListResponse.getItems();

            // TODO: Get the name of the game the broadcasts are associated with
            }

        } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
            System.err.println("GoogleJsonResponseException code: " + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : "
                    + e.getDetails().getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            System.err.println("Throwable: " + t.getMessage());
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

As you can see, the TODO in the snippet above highlights what I am trying to do.

To make it more clear, here is an example of a broadcast in the browser. Please make note that it displays the name of the game "Fortnite":
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ex6EM.jpg

Comment:  This is an “I want a pony” type of question and these are difficult to answer concisely and that makes them off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you can, make an attempt and then show us your code we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level. Even a small amount of code, however incomplete or broken, can give us context and illustrate your intentions. If you really don't know where to start and need guidance consider using services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Comment: @tadman, this question is asking at a point that comes before code. currently, youtube live displays data such as the game that the streamer is playing, but this data seems to not exist in the live streaming api. let me edit my original question so i can be of more help

Comment: If it comes before code, it's not really for Stack Overflow. Treat Stack Overflow like a mechanic for broken code, not code that doesn't exist and needs to be designed and implemented. That's a job for another site, like those I linked to, where people can help walk you through that process.

Comment: @tadman google links stack overflow out for all support requests regarding this api

Comment: Yes, given some code we can look at and fix. You're not that far along yet, though.

Comment: @tadman please see revisions. hopefully my code snippet gives you context and illustrates my intentions. Additionally, please see the link I added as well so you can have a visual aid

Comment: That's a lot better now. Just be sure to tag that with the appropriate language so the right people can get involved. TypeScript?

Comment: @tadman tag updated to reflect im using java :)